# How can I append html to my QWebEngineView

Tags: python, html, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

So in PyQt4 you could do something like this to append html to your page:

```
webView.page().mainFrame().documentElement().appendInside(some_html)
```

I was trying to find similar functionality in PyQt5's `QWebEngineView` but i couldn't find anything useful.

My problem is that i want to load many html files on one page, and it takes like 10 seconds to do that(means that main GUI thread is blocked during that 10 seconds, and my application is unresponsive).

So my solution was to display first 5, and when user presses the button, it loads next 5(with technique described above), and so on.

So my question is: Does `QWebEngineView` has this functionality, and is there some other way to deal with big or many html files in `QWebEngineView`.

Comment: some feedback??

Answer (score 1):

[`documentElement()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#documentElement) is a [`QWebElement`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwebelement.html) and according to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html#unavailable-qt-webkit-api) is not available in `Qt WebEngine`.

The documentation recommends using `javascript` to replace this type of tasks, for example the following code adds html to the `QwebEngineView`:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QDateTime

html = '''
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>
'''

def append():
    some_html = "<p>{}</p>".format(QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString())
    page.runJavaScript("document.body.innerHTML += '{}'".format(some_html))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
view = QWebEngineView()
timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(append)
page = view.page()
page.loadFinished.connect(lambda: timer.start(1000))
page.setHtml(html)
view.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```